# Scroll to a postion in a Web Browser using Wpf

Tags: wpf, indexing, browser, scroll, position

I cannot seem to programmatcally scroll in WPF
in a normal Windows Form I would use the code below
but that property does not exist in WPF.

```
HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
doc.Body.ScrollTop = 800;
return;
```

Is there an alternative to doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Not exaclty sure what to look for in that code, but I basically have a WebControl that shows a Webpage that has several articles. 
I would like to jump to an article by it's title. I know I can get the index of the article name, but jumping to it is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if (wb.Document is mshtml.HTMLDocument htmlDoc)
{
    htmlDoc.parentWindow.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```