# How to Scroll a WPF WebBrowser programmatically?

Tags: wpf, browser, scroll

In Windows Forms Applications Im using the following Code to scroll the Page inside a Webbrowser:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser.Document;
 mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 htmldoc = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)doc.DomDocument;
 htmldoc.parentWindow.scrollBy(265, 20);
```

Does anyone know how to do the same in an WPF Application (without using WindowsFormsHost)?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238792/scroll-to-a-postion-in-a-web-browser-using-wpf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using [System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) class take a look at the [Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.document.aspx) property. You should be able to cast it to mshtml.HTMLDocument or mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 and code

```
mshtml.HTMLDocument htmlDoc = webBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
if (htmlDoc != null) htmlDoc.parentWindow.scrollBy(265, 20);
```

should be working fine for you.

hope this helps, regards

Comment: FYI, this only worked for me when I placed it in the _LoadCompleted() event. It would not work in any earlier event.

Comment: Is mshtml available in .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

you should do it easily :

```
    private void WebBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        ((WebBrowser)sender).InvokeScript("eval", "$( document ).scrollTop( 1700 );");
    }
```

Comment: `.scrollTop()` have no argument.! Remove that `1700`

Comment: The InvokeScript line is throwing a COMException: Unknown name. And that's with or without the 1700.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript:

> window.onload=toBottom;
>
> function toBottom() { alert("Scrolling to bottom ...");
>   window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); }

The HTML:

```
> <html>
>     <head>
>         <script src="testme.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>
>         Some big text<br>           
>     </body>
> </html>
```